# Parallel Kernel inheritance problem for Protect

Tags: parallelization, kernel, protect

for the following program:

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
ParallelTable[0^0, {4}]
```

I have the following result:

> (kernel 1) Power::indet :  Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered. 
> (kernel 2) Power::indet :  Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered. 
> (kernel 1)Power::indet :  Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered.  
> (kernel 2)Power::indet :  Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered.
> {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate}

This certainly means that the kernels do not inherit the modification of Power since

```
Table[0^0, {4}]
```

leads to:

> {1, 1, 1, 1}

How can I do to propagate the modification of Power to the kernels ?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You need to evaluate the modification of [`Power`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html) in all [`Kernels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Kernels.html). Try using [`ParallelEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelEvaluate.html) like this:

```
ParallelEvaluate[
    CompoundExpression[
       Unprotect[Power],
       Power[0, 0] = 1,
       Protect[Power]
    ]
];
```

Now

```
ParallelTable[0^0, {4}]
(* {1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```